Install an extension to multiple profiles
There is a setting for installing the extension for all other profiles. But I want to select the profiles.
I am making profile for wordpress, drupal and laravel. Therefore, there will be some php related extensions that I can share among these 3 profiles. I cannot choose to share among all profiles because I have profiles for python, reactjs and nodejs as well.
Is there an option using which I can select the profiles among which I want to share the extension?
